# Microsoft Access VBA Run Time Error 2465

Tags: ms-access, vba, runtime-error, ms-access-2010

I am currently working on a form to update fields in my database. The button (cmdFind) is meant to find the record for the part # (entered into text box txtFindPart), and then populate the data into In1-52 and out1-52. When I run it I get `Run-time Error 2465 Microsoft Access can not find the field '|1' referred to in your expression.`

```
Private Sub cmdFind_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    If IsNull(txtFindPart) = False Then
        If Me.Recordset.NoMatch Then
            MsgBox "No record found", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Sorry"
            Me!txtFindPart = Null
        End If
        Do Until i = 53
            Me.Controls("in" & i) = DLookup("[In-Week " & i & "]", [Parts], "(([Parts].[Part #]) = '" & txtFindPart & "')")
            Me.Controls("out" & i) = DLookup("[Out-Week " & i & "]", [Parts], "(([Parts].[Part #]) = '" & txtFindPart & "')")
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you have at least 107 fields in one table? :O you should rethink your database design, ASAP! Back to the question: what is the value of `txtFindPart`? Maybe something like `bla'|1 blubb`? At what line does the error occur?

Comment: Its default value is `null` its only when a value is entered that it gets a value to it. When I go to debug it highlights `Me.Controls("in" & i) = DLookup("[In-Week " & i & "]", [Parts], "(([Parts].[Part #]) = '" & txtFindPart & "')")`.

Comment: The problem seems to be in your txtFindPart field in your form, IMHO.

Comment: What would you recommend as a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out the problem was that the table `Parts` Was not open and it was causing the error. I just had to add a line to open the table and at the end close it.

```
DoCmd.OpenTable "Parts"
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
If IsNull(txtFindPart) = False Then
    If Me.Recordset.NoMatch Then
        MsgBox "No record found", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Sorry"
        Me!txtFindPart = Null
    End If
    Do Until i = 53
        Me.Controls("in" & i) = DLookup("[In-Week " & i & "]", "[Parts]", "(([Parts].[Part #]) = '" & txtFindPart & "')")
        Me.Controls("out" & i) = DLookup("[Out-Week " & i & "]", "[Parts]", "(([Parts].[Part #]) = '" & txtFindPart & "')")
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End If
DoCmd.Close , "Parts"
```